# $Z$ standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, notation, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm stuck in a notation problem which I cannot clarify:
I have a text which says :
$x = \text{some constant}* Z\left(\frac{[S(t)-S(t-1)]}{\text{standard deviation of S}}\right)$
with $Z$ standard normal distribution.
Now my question is: how should I interpret that $Z(\text{something})$?
I don't have any other information about this formula and I don't understand when it says $Z$(one variable).

edit to be more clear:
I don't understand what is $Z$(one variable)
is the z-score associated to that variable?
is the standard normal distribution associated to that variable?
don't think it's the second since should have 2 parameters
is it the cdf of the standard normal distribution for that variable and it's the same as writing $P(X < \text{one variable}) =$?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $Z$ refers to the centered-reduced cumulative distribution, which takes a single argument.